# How to refactor a Ruby block and extract repetitive calls into methods?

Tags: ruby, aws-lambda, closures, aws-cloudformation

In [cfndsl](https://github.com/cfndsl/cfndsl), you can create an AWS CloudFormation template like this:

```rb
CloudFormation do
  EC2_Instance(:Example) do
    ImageId 'ami-12345678'
    InstanceType 't1.micro'
  end
end
```

Real-world templates are usually much larger, but that's not the point.

Let's say that I have dozens of `CloudFormation` blocks that share the same `EC2_Instance`, each with a possibly different `ImageId` and `InstanceType`.

How can I extract this repeating pattern into a method (e.g. `ec2_instance`) so that I can refactor the `CloudFormation` block into something like this:

```rb
def ec2_instance(ami, type)
   # ???
end

CloudFormation do
  ec2_instance('ami-12345678', 't1.micro')
end

CloudFormation do
  ec2_instance('ami-90111213', 't2.small')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use the same code, but just replace the ImageId and InstanceType with variables:

```
def ec2_instance(ami, type)
  EC2_Instance(:Example) do
    ImageId ami
    InstanceType type
  end
end
```